# RestController with JpaRepository returning javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin

Using Kotlin, I have these dependencies:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))

implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
```

this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table")
data class SomeEntity(
    @Id val someNumber: Int,
    val someText: String
)
```

with this repository `interface SomeRepo : JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Int>` and this controller:

```
@RestController("/someEntity")
class SomeController(
    val someRepo: SomeRepo
) {
    @GetMapping
    fun findAll() = someRepo.findAll()
}
```

but I always get this exception `javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [com.controller.SomeController@10ffe32f]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler` when I try `localhost:8080/someEntity`

changing `findAll` to `@GetMapping fun findAll(): List<SomeEntity> = listOf(SomeEntity(1, "a"))` didn't solve. What I'm missing here?

Comment: try adding `@RequestMapping` on your class

Comment: thanks @sidgate. I discovered the text inside `@RestController` is not the same thing as the text inside `@ResquestMapping`. If you don't mind, please write your suggestion as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` passed in `@RequestController` is not the URL mapping but the name of Spring bean. The root mapping has to be provided explicitly at class level using `@RequestMapping` or on each method with `@GetMapping`/`@PostMapping`..

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/someEntity")
class SomeController(
    val someRepo: SomeRepo
) {
    @GetMapping
    fun findAll() = someRepo.findAll()
}
```

or

```
@RestController
class SomeController(
    val someRepo: SomeRepo
) {
    @GetMapping("/someEntity")
    fun findAll() = someRepo.findAll()
}
```